# pandas 日付のソートが上手くいきません

Tags: python, pandas, sort

pandasにてソートを行なったのですが、日付（判明日）の部分だけ、上手くソートされません。日の部分が二桁の際には上手く並び替えられているのですが、どうしても日が一桁の日時が無視してソートされてしまいます。どのようにすれば解決するでしょうか。

```
df_sort=df3.sort_values(["居住地","判明日"])
df_sort.head(50)`
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**判明日列**が 文字列型（str型）なのではないですか？

試しに

```
print(df['判明日'].dtype)
```

を実行してみて、`object` という結果が得られたら文字列です。

文字列のソートの場合、単純に文字列の先頭から比較しますので、例えば `'2020/3/9'` と `'2020/3/10'` の比較では、文字列の先頭から`'2020/3/'`までが同じ値で、次の `'9'` と `'1'` の比較となるので `'2020/3/10'` の方が**小さい値**と判断されてしまいます。

ということで、この場合は素直'判明日'列をdatetime型に変換した後にソートするべきかと思います。

```
df3['判明日'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['判明日'])
sorted_df = df3.sort_values(['居住地','判明日'])
```

この方法であれば**判明日列**を日時データの比較でソートを行いますので、求める結果が得られると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事上手く実行できました。